# Bootstrap 4 Footer is not placed at the bottom

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I would like to create a simple main page with a footer section using `bootstrap-4`. In this example I have a main section and a footer section, which in the code is below the main section and also is styed with `bottom: 0;` but strangely in browser view or mobile view it is in the middle of the screen.

[JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/saitam/4vcaz7td/30/)

HTML:

```
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 mt-100">
        <h1 class="mb-4">Some Text</h1>
        <p style="text-align:justify;" class="lead">
          Some text some text Some text some textSome text some textSome text 
          some textSome text some textSome text some textSome text some textSome text some textSome text some textSome text some textSome text some textSome text some textSome text some textSome text some textSome text some textSome text some textSome text some textSome text some textSome text some textSome text some textSome text  text some text Some text some textSome text  text some textSome text some textSome text text some textSome text some textSome
        </p>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 mt-100">
        <div class="text-center">
          <p>
          Some more Text Some more Text Some more TextSome more TextSome more TextSome more TextSome more TextSome more Text
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
</section>

<section>
  <footer class="page-footer">
    <p class="text-center">THIS IS THE FOOTER</p>
  </footer>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
html,
body {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.mt-100 {
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.main-image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url("http://afreshstartmovingco.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/hd-wallpapers-1920x1080-nature-1-1568x882.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 0% 100%;
}

.page-footer {
  background-color: #343a40;
  color: white;
  padding: 30px 30px 30px 30px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your HTML & CSS Like

```
   <!-- MAIN SECTION WITH BACKGROUND IMAGE-->
<div class="d-flex flex-column h-100"> /*Change HERE*/
<section class="main-image flex-fill">  /*Change HERE*/
  <!-- MAIN CONTENT-->
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
        <h1 class="mb-4">Some Text</h1>
        <p style="text-align:justify;" class="lead">
          Some 
        </p>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 mt-100">
        <div class="text-center">
          <p>
          Some more Text Some more Text Some more TextSome more TextSome more TextSome more TextSome more TextSome more Text
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</section>

<!-- FOOTER SECTION-->
<section>
  <footer class="page-footer">
    <p class="text-center">THIS IS THE FOOTER</p>
  </footer>
</section>
</div>  /*Change HERE*/


html,
body {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}


.mt-100 {
  margin-top: 100px;
}


.main-image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh; /* remove this*/
  /* responsive */
  background-image: url("http://afreshstartmovingco.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/hd-wallpapers-1920x1080-nature-1-1568x882.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 0% 100%;
}


.page-footer {
  background-color: #343a40;
  color: white;
  padding: 30px 30px 30px 30px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* min-height:10vh; */
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/27y53fzp/5/

Answer (score -1):

It's because your page content is small and does not fill the page height,
you might want to make the `position:relative;` and then make `bottom:0;`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Please read the code or check the fiddle example. It already is `position: relative;`.

Comment: @saitam on my screen the footer is already on the bottom correctly, how ever depending on the screen you might want to change the `display` attribute